# How to get the PropertyType of indexed property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, viewmodel

I am working with DataBinding in DataGrid. I have a viewmodel which has a property called **MyDataSource** of type List. Class1 has a property called **MyList** of type List. Class2 has a property called **MyProperty** of type string.

**My DataGrid xaml looks like.**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSource}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyValue" Binding="{Binding Path=MyList[0].MyProperty}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here I have access to PropertyPath **MyList[0].MyProperty** and MyDataSource in code. Now I want to find out PropertyType for **MyProperty** by passing **MyList[0].MyProperty** in GetProperty method.

I followed the method described in the following link. But here the PropertyInfo is null for MyList[0].
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Reflection/Getsapropertysparentobject.htm

Edited:

I also tried the following code:

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = MyDataSource.GetType().GetProperty(MyList[0].MyProperty)
```

But pInfo returns null here.

Can anybody please suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to achieve but you could use a ValueConverter like:

```
  class MyConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      var typeName = ((Class2)value).GetType().GetProperty((string) parameter);
      return typeName.ToString();
    }
```

And XAML Binding:

```
<Window x:Class="ThemeTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:ThemeTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:MyConverter x:Key="propertyToParentTypeConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

...

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSource}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyValue">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource propertyToParentTypeConverter}"  ConverterParameter="MyProperty" Path="MyList[0]" />
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

---

If you need to traverse a chain of properties where one property is a collection then you can use reflection in the following way:

```
  PropertyInfo pInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperty("MyDataSource");
  if (pInfo != null && pInfo.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System.Collections"))
  {
    foreach (object obj in ((IEnumerable)pInfo.GetValue(myObject, null)))
    {
      PropertyInfo pInfoElement = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyList");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't know the target type (say Class2) of the indexed property. I have to find it programatically.

Comment: I am trying to find out the PropertyType of MyProperty. I have access to MyDataSource and MyList[0].MyProperty path in code. Now how can I find out the PropertyType of MyProperty. I tried the code: PropertyInfo pInfo = MyDataSource.GetType().GetProperty(MyList[0].MyProperty) but pInfo returns null here.

Comment: Reason for MyDataSource.GetType().GetProperty(MyList[0].MyProperty) to return null is that "MyProperty" is not a property on the class that MyDataSource is a instance of.

You can do this:
var pInfo = (MyList[0]).GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty");

Comment: Strange, if you add an break point at that line, do you have any value at all on "MyList[0]"?

Comment: In Immediate Window i get:

(MyDataSource[0].MyList[0]).GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty")
{System.String MyProperty}
    [System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo]: {System.String MyProperty}
    base {System.Reflection.MemberInfo}: {System.String MyProperty}
    Attributes: None
    CanRead: true
    CanWrite: true
    IsSpecialName: false
    MemberType: Property
    PropertyType: {Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}

Comment: Fredrik, can you please check out the this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Reflection/Getsapropertysparentobject.htm. I am trying to follow the similar approach to find out the PropertyPath for MyList[0].MyProperty, but here propertyInfo is returning null. This method is working well when MyList is not a collection. I tried using Class2.MyProperty to find out the PropertyPath, it works well. How can I achieve it using a collection (say MyList)?